# Testing significance of random effects in a linear mixed-effects model with interactions

Tags: interaction, lme4-nlme, mixed-model

I would like to test the significance of all interactions in a 3 factor linear mixed-effects model. Factors A and B are fixed, and factor C is random. Using `lmer`, the full model is:

```
lmer(response ~ A*B + (1 + A*B|C), data.frame)
```

My question concerns getting p-values for the 2-way interactions and the main effect of C. I initially planned to use likelihood ratio tests to compare this full model to reduced models by removing one interaction at a time. But of course specifying the 3-way interaction automatically includes the 2-way interactions and main effect of C.

So I would like to know if there is a way to construct a reduced model that includes the 3-way interaction and omits only a single 2-way interaction (or the main effect of C).

But of course the LR-test has its limitations. I would appreciate any advice on other ways to obtain p-values for random effects in this model. I am aware of `RLRsim`, MCMC, `bootMer`. Are any of these preferable/more feasible for my situation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13502815/exclude-one-factor-level-interaction-calculation-in-lme4 does this help

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. It doesn't seem to be working in my case, will have to investigate further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** This is *possible*, but very tedious (especially for factors with more than 2 levels), and you might not want to do it after all.  If you can decide exactly what you *mean to test* by testing the lower-level interactions, you can probably do it.

This is a little bit tricky partly for technical R-specific reasons, and partly for statistical/inferential reasons.

The statistically tricky part is that testing lower-level interactions in a model that also contains higher-level interactions is (depending on who you talk to) either (i) hard to do correctly or (ii) just plain silly (for the latter position, see part 5  of Bill Venables's "exegeses on linear models". The rubric for this is the *principle of marginality*.  At the very least, the *meaning* of the lower-order terms depends sensitively on how contrasts in the model are coded (e.g. treatment vs. midpoint/sum-to-zero). My default rule is that if you're not **sure** you understand exactly why this might be a problem, you shouldn't violate the principle of marginality.

The technically tricky part is that R's formula language doesn't have a simple way to drop lower-order terms in the presence of higher-order interactions (in part because this stuff was all designed originally by researchers from the Nelder/Venables camp that doesn't think this is a sensible thing to do).  I have done this in the past, in cases where I knew it was sensible, by constructing the model matrix, dropping the columns I didn't want, and using the remaining terms as explicit variables in the model.  In particular, I had terms `period` (before vs. after) and `ttt` (treatment: control vs. removal) and wanted to measure the `period:ttt` interaction  but setting the before-period difference between treatments to zero: for the default ("treatment") contrasts in R, this corresponds to setting $\beta_{\textrm{ttt}}$ to zero, or removing that column from the model matrix.

```
dd <- expand.grid(period=c("before","after"),
                  ttt=c("control","removal"))
## some trickery to get factor levels in the sensible order
dd[] <- lapply(dd,function(x) factor(x,levels=unique(x)))
```

You might think that `~period*ttt-period` would be the way to specify the desired result, but it doesn't actually work:

```
colnames(model.matrix(~period*ttt-ttt,dd))
## [1] "(Intercept)"             "periodafter"            
## [3] "periodbefore:tttremoval" "periodafter:tttremoval"
```

(neither does `~period+period:ttt`, or any other sensible combination I could think of).  Instead:

```
X <- model.matrix(~period*ttt,dd)
## also remove the intercept because this will get re-added
X <- X[,!colnames(X) %in% c("(Intercept)","tttremoval")]
colnames(X) <- c("period","period_ttt")  ## friendlier names
```

Now we can fit a model with `y~period+period_ttt,data=X` and get what we want.

How does this translate to your case?

> the full model is:

```
lmer(response ~ A*B + (1 + A*B|C), data.frame)
```

> My question concerns getting p-values for the 2-way interactions and the main effect of C.

If you want a p-value for the interaction of `A:B` you should probably compare the model above to

```
update(model, . ~ A + B + (1 + A + B | C))
```

I'm not sure what the "main effect of C" is -- is that the variation of the intercept among levels
of `C` ?  If so, you probably have to use the trick above to exclude the intercept from `A*B`, e.g.

```
update(model, . ~ A*B + (A2 + B2 + A2_B2 | C))
```

where `A2`, `B2`, and `A2_B2` are dummy variables as above.

But it's up to you to make sure this makes sense.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful, thanks. Precisely the explanation I needed (and as far as I can tell is not available anywhere else).